# Where to put methods that interact with multiple classes

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a class called `Contact` and one called `Account`

and I have a method called `public static Account GetAccount(Contact c) {...}`

Where is the best place to put this method?  What design patterns should I be looking at?

A) With the Contact class

B) With the Account class

C) Have the method accessible in both classes

D) Somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many good answers to your question. I'll take a stab at an answer, but it will have my personal biases baked in it.

In OOP, you generally don't see globally accessible) functions, disconnected from, but available to all classes. (Static methods might be globally available, but they are still tied to a particular class). To follow up on dkatzel's answer, a common pattern is in OOP is *instance manager*. You have a class or instance that provides access to a a database, file store, REST service, or some other place where Contact or Account objects are saved for future use.

You might be using a persistence framework with your Python project. Maybe something like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/

Some persistence frameworks create handy methods instance methods like Contact.getAccount() -- send the getAccount message to a contact and the method return the associated Account object. ...Or developers can add these sorts of convenience methods themselves.

Another kind of convenience method can live on the static side of a class. For example, the Account class could have a static getAccountForContact() method that returns a particular account for a given Contact object. This method would access the instance manager and use the information in the contact object to look up the correct account.

Usually you would not add a static method to the Contact class called getAccountForContact(). Instead, you would create an instance method on Contact called getAccount(). This method could then call Account.getAccountForContact() and pass "self" in as the parameter. (Or talk to an instance manager directly).

My guiding principle is typically DRY - do not repeat yourself. I pick the option that eliminates the most copy-and-paste code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the lookup from Contact to Account happens but I would vote for putting it in a new class that uses the `Repository` pattern.

```
Repository repo = ...

Account account = repo.getAccount(contact);
```

That way you can have multiple Repository implemtations that look up the info from a database, or an HTTP request or internal mapping etc. and you don't have to modify the code that uses the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

If you define your method in this way, it's not really connected with either of your classes. You can as well put it in a `Util` class:

```
public class AccountUtil{
    public static Account getAccount(Contact c){ ... }
    // you can put other methods here, e.g.
    public static Contact getContact(Account a){ ... }
}
```

This follows the pattern of grouping static functions in utility classes like `Math` in Java / C#.

If you would like to bound the function to a class in a clear way, consider designing your class like this:

```
public class Contact{
    public Account getAccount(){ ... } // returns the Account of this Contact
    // other methods
}
```

In OOP it is generally recommended that you avoid using global functions when possible. If you want a static function anyways, I'd put it in a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for a new class, especially if the function returns an existing account object. That is, if you have a collection of instances of Contact and a collection of instances of Account and this function maps one to the other, use a new class to encapsulate this mapping.

Otherwise, it probably makes sense as a method on `Contact` if `GetAccount` returns a new account filled in from a template. This would hold if `GetAccount` is something like a factory method for the Account class, or if the Account class is just a record type (instances of which have lifetimes which are bound to instances of `Contact`).

The only way I see this making sense as part of `Account` is if it makes sense as a constructor.